# Quaternion to Matrix using glm

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to convert quat in glm to mat4.

My code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include<glm/common.hpp>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    glm::mat4 MyMatrix=glm::mat4();
    glm::quat myQuat;

    myQuat=glm::quat(0.707107,0.707107,0.00,0.000);
    glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = quaternion::toMat4(myQuat);

    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;++j)
        {
            cout<<RotationMatrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i run the program it shows the error "error: ‘quaternion’ has not been declared".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does `quaternion::toMat4` need to be `glm::quaternion::toMat4`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the include:

```
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
```

And fix the namespace of `toMat4`:

```
glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::toMat4(myQuat);
```

`glm::toMat4()` exists in the `gtx/quaternion.hpp` file, which [you can see](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00077_source.html) only has the `glm` namespace.

---

Also as a side note, as of C++14, nested namespaces (e.g. glm::quaternion::toMat4) [are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3603461/1105042).

Comment: Nested namespace *definitions* are not allowed in C++14, but there are none defined in the question... anyway, they are allowed in C++17.

Comment: It was mentioned in the comments, but in hindsight I should have responded there.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to meepzh's answer, it can also be done like this:

```
glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(myQuat);
```

which **does not** require `#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>`

Comment: On Fedora-32 desktop (Linux) it does require the above include.